# What is this purple-flowered weed?

Tags: identification, weeds

It looks it is a weed, but not so bad. I saw it in an urban area in Europe, Hardiness Zone 8a.

Is it poisonous, or nasty in any other way?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a mallow (Malva), see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malva. I think *Malva sylvestris*.

It is not a weed, it was often planted as drug, because it (supposedly) can cure a lot of common illness. In any case, it is also frequent in Europe.

Comment: It acts like a weed, pops up everywhere

Comment: My mother always said that a weed is just a plant that's in the wrong place.

Comment: One gardener‘s weed is another‘s prized possession....

Comment: One thing about it that is kind of unfavorable: if you do want to get rid of it, it's not easy after a while. Every year it gets bigger and tougher, and the root gets more entrenched.